# intellij Terminal environment variable set global

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, intellij-14

I'm trying to set a environment variable for the intellij terminal gobally for all projects. Up to now I only found the setting in File>Settings>Tools>Terminal but somehow this is not applied throughout all projects.

Is there a way to set this globally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File | New Project Settings | Settings for New Projects...

It will apply only to the new projects. At the moment [there is no way to globally change the settings for the existing projects](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221422).

If you need a global environment variable, consider setting it in the OS configuration instead.

In case the goal is to detect if your app/script is running inside IntelliJ IDEA Terminal, you can use `TERMINAL_EMULATOR=JetBrains-JediTerm` environment variable for that.

Comment: Ah ok, only for new projects, that makes sense. Actually I want to set the env variable because I want to be able to detect in my shell startup file whether it was launched by intellij (so setting it OS wide won't help).  But thanks anyway, now I know that these settings will only apply to new projects.

Comment: Terminal launched from the IDE will have some specific environment variables set that you can use to detect it: `IDEA_INITIAL_DIRECTORY`, `__INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__`, `TERMINAL_EMULATOR=JetBrains-JediTerm`.

Comment: It was the last one (the other two were not set). Thanks ;)    Would you like to include that into your answer?